# Is there any way to call the move assignment operator in C++ without std::move?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I wonder if it is possible to call the move assignment operator without using the standard
library std::move.

So for example if I call :

```
class A {
    private:
        char* data;
    public:
        // move constructor
        A(A&& other) : data(other.data) {
            // we steal the pointer!
            other.data = NULL;
        }
        // move operator=
        A& operator=(A&& other) {
            if (this != &other) {
                delete data;
                data = other.data;
                data.foo = NULL;
        }
            return *this;
        }
};

int main(){
    A objA; 
    A objB; 
    objB = std::move(objA);
}
```

can I now write something other than `objB = std::move(objA);` ?

Comment: You can do `objB = A();` to reassign from a newly created, unnamed value. Similarly, you could assign the result of a function that returns an `A`. But otherwise, you're using `std::move` or implementing your own equivalent function or cast; it's a little unclear *why* you want to do this though; can you provide a *reason* so we could answer more effectively?

Comment: Your question is clear enough, but please try to make your example reproducible. You don't have a default constructor, so the code in `main` doesn't compile. Also, what is `data.foo`?

Comment: Unrelated: Since C++14, there's a nifty little function called [`std::exchange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange) that you could use in your move constructor to make it `A(A&& other) : data(std::exchange(other.data, nullptr)) {}`

Comment: What is `data.foo = NULL;` supposed to do? Did you mean `other.data = nullptr;`?

Comment: Add a member function `A&& operator+() { return static_cast<A&&>(*this); }` then you can do `objB = +objA;`.  Too bad C++ doesn't have a unary `operator&&`.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any way to call the move assignment operator in C++ without std::move?

`std::move` is a very simple function that merely performs a cast. You can write that cast instead of calling the function:

```
objB = static_cast<A&&>(objA);
```

I don't know of a practical reason for doing this.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion: this cast works fine here, but the actual implementation of `std::move` is a bit more subtle, to deal with calling it on a reference. +1.

Comment: @PeteBecker Only because the template arg is [usually] deduced; the shown code is indeed equivalent to a call to `std::move(objA)`, because we give the argument explicitly for `static_cast`. If you templated it then yes you'd need to remove_reference too. Same if you attempted `static_cast<decltype(objA)>(objA)` for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to keep `objA` as a named local variable then, no, there is no way to pass it to a constructor of `objB` and have the constructor being invoked be the move constructor, short of using `std::move` (or equivalent things that similarly return `T&&` to make the expression be an *rvalue* `T`, like a `static_cast<A&&>`).

That's by design. It should not be possible to accidentally move from a named, declared object; you should have to ask for it. That's why `std::move` is called `std::move`, despite not actually performing any move itself: its name strongly signals the usual intent of using it.

The other way to invoke a move constructor is to pass an expression that was never going to be an *lvalue* in the first place, such as one that creates a temporary.